# MS Access SQL Query - Find record order

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

would like to ask how do we find out the 'numbering order' of a record.

My sql query -

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE field2=444
ORDER BY field1

   field1 field2
1) 2/9/17 111
2) 3/9/17 222
3) 5/9/17 333
4) 8/9/17 444
5) 9/9/17 555
```

It would return 4 as 444 is on the Fourth record. Please advice.

p/s - we hv a large DB so select * and compare each will be not efficient

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery or DCount to count all rows lower than the previous one:

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(Field1) FROM tableName As B WHERE b.Field1 <= a.Field1) As numberingOrder, *
FROM tableName As A
WHERE field2=444
ORDER BY field1
```

And for only the distinct values, as asked in comments:

```
SELECT (
     SELECT Count(Field1) 
     FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM tableName
     ) As B 
     WHERE b.Field1 <= a.Field1
) As numberingOrder, *
FROM tableName As A
WHERE field2=444
ORDER BY field1
```

Comment: hi, will that work? as the sample field2(111,222,333.... is just dummy. the real value will be 4 digit random number) . thanks,

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why I post it as an answer. As long as you're consistent in your fields (field1 is the field you're ordering by).

Comment: hi, it works perfectly!

but we hv another issue - as we hv duplicate record on the same date -
 on field1. is it possible to use DISTINCT field1 so it will return as 1 even if we hv few or more record on the same date?

Thank You,

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you there. See the current edit for a distinct count.

Comment: Cool man. It works Perfectly now! how do we rate the answer and close this thread?

Comment: You don't need to close it. Just hit the check mark beneath the one left of my answer. You can upvote by hitting the ^ above the one, and downvote by hitting the thing under the one. Questions and answers stay visible, so other users may benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Position_Of_Where_Clause
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.field1 <= (SELECT TOP 1 s.field1
                   FROM YourTable s
                   WHERE s.field2 = 444
                   ORDER BY s.field1)
```

Comment: hi, it works perfectly when we test with the dummy DB. but it throws an error when we test on the real DB as we hv duplicate value in field2 - 'at most one record can be returned by this subquery'

Comment: how do we fix it so it will return the first 'order'? thank you.

Comment: You can add an `ORDER BY` clause and select `TOP 1` @aboka

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: It's exactly what I did lol.. I already edited the query.. @aboka

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fourth record *and* the values are all distinct, then you can use `SELECT TOP` twice:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.*
FROM (SELECT TOP 4 t.*
      FROM tableName as t
      WHERE field2 = 444
      ORDER BY field1
     ) as t
ORDER BY field1 DESC;
```

Comment: That's not what he asked for.. he just want `4` .

Comment: hi, the value are not distinct and we would like to find the 'ordering' or the record. any suggestions? thanks

Comment: "the value are not distinct" - if so, there is no way to order them, and there shouldn't be. A database is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: hi, we just need to find out the record order number. is it possible? thanks.